# buttons within spinner items

Tags: android

I have a created a spinner for my application in android. How can I add a small button (or clickable image) at each item in which when you click on it, it takes you down one items in the spinner? Kinda of like "get me the next item " button without having to expand the whole list.

Thank you very much

An example is, I have my spinner

- item 1_***_*____**_arrowDown
- item 2_***_*____**_arrowDown
- item 3_***_*____**_arrowDown

So when you click on item 1, then this is the selected item. But when you click on arrowDown of item1, it chooses item2 as the selected value. If you click on arrowDown of item 2 then it chooses item 3 as the selected value. arrowDown can be a button or clickable image.

Comment: You want a button inside spinner or nearby that spinner. If near the spinner, then this can be done.

Comment: I want a button inside the spinner as part of the drop down items

Comment: So you want a button scroll-able spinner with limited items?

Comment: I will add more decription to the question

Answer (score 0):

set DropDown resource of spinner to a xml file add button in that file

Comment: Aashish, thanks but can you be more specific? I have my spinner XML under Values folder and it is called String.xml as android tutorial suggests. I have the spinner grabbing items from there <item></item> so where do I add the button? IF you can show me an example or point me to an example, then that would be great. Thanks